# There is no implicit conversion between bool and System.DayOfWeek

Tags: c#

I want to add into a List days if checkboxes are checked so i do the following:

```
List<DayOfWeek> result = rbDaily.Checked || rbTwoWeeks.Checked 
              ? new List<DayOfWeek>
              { 
                  checkboxMon.Checked ? true : DayOfWeek.Monday, checkboxWed.Checked ? true : DayOfWeek.Wednesday
              }
              : null;
```

somehow it says for those lines:

```
checkboxMon.Checked ? true : DayOfWeek.Monday
checkboxWed.Checked ? true : DayOfWeek.Wednesday
```

There is no implicit conversion between bool and System.DayOfWeek. What should i put there additionally to say not add that day if false is returned?

Comment: `checkboxMon.Checked ? true : DayOfWeek.Monday` doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: @canton7 as i said if that checbox is not checked (false) do not add that day to the list otherwise add

Comment: [Conditional operator specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) says _The type of consequent and alternative must be the same, or there must be an implicit conversion from one type to the other._ You should return `DayOfWeek` in both cases

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski  i understand that but i dont know what should i put into false condition because there will be no item to be added to list in this case when checkboxMon.Checked is false

Comment: There's no way to do what you want using a collection initialiser. You need to do `var list = new List<DayOfWeek>(); if (checkboxMon.Checked) list.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday);` etc

Comment: You can't have conditional initialization. You're trying to stuff too much in a single line. Split it up, mix in a newline, have a few `if`s, unwind this unnecessarily tight and confusing package of conditions.

Comment: _" if that checbox is not checked (false) do not add that day to the list otherwise add"_ ok. What your code _actually_ says is "create a new list of DayOfWeek. Add one item to it. If chkBoxMon is checked, then add "true" to the list. If it's not checked add "Monday" to the list. Clearly, you cannot add "true" to the list because it's not a day of the week - and that's what the error is telling you. You've got two logical problems there. The main one is that you're adding _something_ to the list, no matter what - by the time you're examining the value of the checkbox it's already too late.

Comment: @ADyson i know that but i am trying to find a way to do it in conditional initialization.

Comment: @Arie I was just pointing out that your code doesn't even come to close to doing what you said you thought  / hoped it was doing, and helping you to understand why. Anyway there is no possible way to do it using the collection initialiser inside the `{ ... }`, because anything you put in there is always added to the list. In there you cannot decide _if_ you add something, you can only decide _what_ to add. You must initialise the list, and then add items to it separately on subsequent lines, using `if` statements to decide whether to go ahead with adding, or not, in each case.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for help

Comment: You can still have your one-liner, if you please (but I'd still break it up with some newlines :-P): `result = new (Checkbox checkbox, DayOfWeek day)[] { (checkboxMon, DayOfWeek.Monday), (checkboxTue, DayOfWeek.Tuesday), ... }.Where(t => t.checkbox.Checked).Select(t => t.day).ToList()`. In general, if there is a way to associate checkboxes with values natively (most GUI frameworks have custom properties for this, or some other way of binding a model) that would be preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way of achieving what you want using a collection initializer.

Split your code up a bit:

```
List<DayOfWeek> result = null;
if (rbDaily.Checked || rbTwoWeeks.Checked)
{
    result = new List<DayOfWeek>();
    if (checkboxMon.Checked)
        result.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday);
    if (checkboxWed.Checked)
        result.Add(DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
}
```

If you have lots of different checkboxes for different days of the week, you can do something like:

```
var checkboxes = new List<(Checkbox checkbox, DayOfWeek dow)>()
{
    (checkboxMon, DayOfWeek.Monday),
    ... etc ...
};

var result = (rbDaily.Checked || rbTwoWeeks.Checked)
    ? checkboxes.Where(x => x.checkbox.Checked).Select(x => x.dow).ToList()
    : null;
```

Comment: In your line here: checkboxes.Where(x => x.checkbox.Checked).Select(x => x.dow).ToList() - if all my days checboxes are not selected i should also get null - how to say that?

Comment: @Arie That was never part of your question! You could start by checking whether any of your checkboxes are checked, or you could see whether you have an empty list and replace it with null

Comment: I see but can it be added somehow to your code easly?

Comment: Sure, by doing the things I suggested in my comment above

Comment: hehe yes i see but can it be somehow add to linq expression rather than to code another line of code? Not expert in linq

Comment: @Arie Remember that the point of code isn't to be as terse as possible: the point of code is to be as easily understandable and maintainable as possible. Don't aim for the tersest possible code which you can force into solving your issue: aim to make your code pretty and clear

Answer (score 3):

According to [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

> The type of consequent and alternative must be the same, or there must
>   be an implicit conversion from one type to the other

You should return the same type for both expressions. You can declare your list as `List<DayOfWeek?>` for example and initialize like that

```cs
? new List<DayOfWeek?>
              { 
                  checkboxMon.Checked ? DayOfWeek.Monday : (DayOfWeek?)null, checkboxWed.Checked ? DayOfWeek.Wednesday : (DayOfWeek?)null
              }
              : null;
```

Or even get rid of the conditional operator and use the code like that

```cs
if (rbDaily.Checked || rbTwoWeeks.Checked)
{
    var list = new List<DayOfWeek>();
    if (checkboxMon.Checked)
        list.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday);
    if (checkboxWed.Checked)
        list.Add(DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
}
```

Comment: keep in mind i do not want to store null inside my list

Comment: @Arie I've added an additional option

Comment: Ya, thats what i thought, i cannot do that using conditional initialization, ok thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to store boolean values in a `List<DayOfWeek>`.  (As well as returning an indeterminate type from a ternary conditional expression.)

Consider the semantics of your description:

> I want to add into a List days if checkboxes are checked

You're describing exactly the code you want.  Express it as pseudo-code:

```
If checkbox is checked {
    Add into a list
}
```

So create your collection, and conditionally add your elements to it.  For example:

```
List<DayOfWeek> result = new List<DayOfWeek>();
if (checkboxMon.Checked)
{
    result.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday);
}
if (checkboxWed.Checked)
{
    result.Add(DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
}
// etc.
```

Comment: thanks, nevertheless i wanted to have that as conditional initialization, this way i know of course :)

Comment: @Arie You can't use the conditional operator to return a value or "nothing". You're tying to force an operator to do something it can't.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator takes a boolean expression and yields two possible outputs that must be of the same type. It can't be used to return a value or "nothing" if the value is false. You want `if` statements instead:

```
List<DayOfWeek> userType = null;

if (rbDaily.Checked || cbTwoWeeks.Checked)
{
    userType = new List<DayOfWeek>();
    if (checkboxMon.Checked)
    { 
        userType.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday);
    }
    if(checkboxWed.Checked)
    { 
        userType.Add(DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
    }
}
```

You *could* do slick things like put the checkboxes in a collection and project to a list using `Where`, etc. but using `if` is probably the cleanest (meaning easiest to read) method.

Answer (score -2):

```
checkboxMon.Checked ? true : DayOfWeek.Monday
```

This not make any sense. true is a bool type and DayOfWeek.Monday is a Date type. Just rewrite your code as

```
if(checkboxMon.Checked)
 new List<DayOfWeek>{DayOfWeek.Monday };
```

Comment: It would be a bit useless if you can't retrieve the list and use it for anything else...

Comment: problem is not about the retrieving the list, its about the adding the date element according to checked date. so rather than the checkboxMon.Checked ? true : DayOfWeek.Monday, this is the correct usage.

Comment: yes but they also need to check Wednesday afterwards and add to the same list. Your code doesn't allow that.

Comment: yeah i just gave the idea

Comment: ok but really the idea of an answer is to give a full solution, like most of the other answers here. A suggestion like yours is still welcome but if you do that, you need to explain the limitations clearly, so people don't assume your code would fully solve the problem.